# Overlapping stack pages , stacked pages are visible one above the other

Tags: angular, ionic2

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUsJ0.jpg)
In the screenshot the first screen is of course page after clicking on a particular course , the course detailed page appears ( by using push() ) , where u can see it got overlapped on course page (the previous page).

Im facing this from last month, can u please help , i googled a lot but didn't got the solution

Im using ionic2 (beta 11)

My html code below:

```
     <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <!--  content list  -->
      </ion-item>
      <ion-row>                 
            <!--  content -->
      </ion-row>
    </ion-list>
```

the above html is inside ion-content tag

Comment: Please add code + versions of ionic.

Comment: any error in console? actually one page is always going to overlap another page, maybe any scss error or transparent background?

Comment: there is no error in the console, if transparency issue how to solve it, coz its coming in many pages is there any solution which solves the issue for all other pages

Comment: it was transparency issue , solved thank u